# Justification of the need for an in-memory database

Tags: java, database, use-case, in-memory-database

My use case is as follows -- 
I have a database table with around 1000+ entries and this table is updated/edited infrequently but i expect this to change in future. Some of the columns in the table contain strings that are of considerable length. 
Now I am in the process of writing a UI application that will have some mouseover events that will display texts derived from the aforementioned database table.

I have, for my use case, decided to write a backend 'server' that will host an in-memory database that will have all the data that was present in the aforementioned table. The UI app will now, on startup, cache the required data from the in-memory database present or hosted by the backend server.

Does my use case justify using an in-memory database ? 
If not, what are the alternatives I should consider ?

EDIT 1 --
My use case also involves running multiple searches of varying complexity on the database very frequently.
Thanks
p1ng

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like an excellent use-case for an in-memory database.  Writing it yourself, on the other hand, is probably not the way to go.

There are plenty of existing options for just about any imaginable scenario: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-memory_database

If you're doing complex searches on text data, [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) is quite excellent.  It has special in-memory storage backends, but really, it doesn't matter for such a tiny dataset - it will always be quickly cached anyway.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri . I may have been unclear. I dont intend to write the in-memory database myself.
Im accepting this as the answer.